# Can Yarn list all available scripts?

Tags: reactjs, bash, terminal, yarnpkg

I have some scripts on my package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel src -d lib",
    "test": "jest"
  }
}
```

Is there a way to list all available scripts from my terminal command `yarn` ?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2965

> Use `yarn run`, just like npm `npm run`

Comment: And here I've been using `cat package.json` for years like a chump.

Comment: I don't suppose there is any way to get it to just list the commands without prompting for a command to run.

Comment: Bypass the prompt with `exit | yarn run`

Answer (score 13):

Another solution is with [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

`jq .scripts package.json`

Output example:

```
{
  "dev": "webpack-dev-server --mode development",
  "build": "webpack --mode production"
}
```

You could add the script to your list of scripts and use `yarn scripts`

```
  "scripts": {
    "scripts": "jq .scripts package.json"
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

`npm run` is too slow, I got response for almost 5 seconds sometimes.

I've been using `cat package.json` for years, but I had to scroll the screen in terminal every time because `package.json` is too long (more than one screen).

So I filter it via `grep` and `sed`.
`grep` print 50 lines after match `scripts`, and `sed` used to match the other parentheses, then quit without continue print.

```sh
$ grep "scripts" -A 50 ./package.json | sed '/}/ q' # run it on package.json directory
```

So I append it to `~/.bashrc` via `alias scripts="grep 'scripts' -A 20 ./package.json | sed '/}/ q'"`.

And next time, I just run `scripts`, then I got all scripts content on `package.json`.

Cool~

Comment: this remark about `npm run` being slow is outdated